# Connotations of the word Triassic

Tags: meaning, slang, offensive-language, business-language

Our company is planning to name a new venture as Triassic... and our user base is native English speakers mostly in the US and rest of the world.

I wanted to check with native speakers does the word "Triassic" have any kind of negative connotations attached to it? Is the word "Triassic" associated with any type of organization/group/movement that will make it inappropriate as a business name? What kind of emotions/vibes/feelings comes to your mind when you hear the word "Triassic" ?

In short, imagine a business name like "Triassic Solutions", is this perfectly ok? Any reason you would rather suggest us not to use the word "Triassic"?

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

The Triassic Period was the first period of the Mesozoic Era, spanning the 50.6 million years between the Permian and Jurassic periods, or 251.902–201.3 million years ago.

Native speakers are unlikely to remember the exact dates, and may not remember that the period was bookended by a pair of major extinction events. They may remember that it has something to do with dinosaurs.  It sounds like Jurassic, which is more familiar, thanks to the movies.

When I hear "Triassic Solutions" I think: *solutions that are really, really, really old*.

Is that negative?  Probably.

Comment: Solutions so old that they are fossilised.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have any associations that make it inappropriate as a business term. However, as the name of a prehistoric era, there's a possibility that it might connote datedness, in the same way as a person or organisation with outdated ideas might be informally described as a *dinosaur*. On the other hand, if the impression you want to give is that your project represents something that's been around since time immemorial, then that could become a positive thing.

I suspect the reason for the [offensive-language](/questions/tagged/offensive-language) tag is the presence of the letters "ass". This won't offend anyone, but a minor consideration is whether an overzealous profanity filter might pick up the word, and either block communications or perform undesirable substitutions such as "tri***ic" or "tributtic". This is known as the [Scunthorpe problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scunthorpe_problem), but in my opinion it's unlikely to be an issue in this case, since there are plenty of other words with this letter sequence (*classic*, *assassin*, *molasses*).